# Deploying a rails app ... how to load first user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Maybe I'm missing something really simple here, I don't know -- I've never deployed a rails app before. I'm about to. I'm using Devise for user authentication, and have several actions that require authentication. The app is not set up so just anyone can register, registration is restricted to a set of users who will administer the app.

But, what I don't know ... is when the app switches to the production database, how do I get myself set up as the first user? The user model will be empty, I won't be able to even access the controllers that would let me set up a new user, because those controllers require authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `/db/seeds.rb`

Check http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the database directly and insert the records manually.

Comment: @Final Draft generate them in the rails console first, then save info and run with it.